# Sort log data with bash

Tags: bash, sort, uniq

I have a log file containing such entries

```
192.168.1.1;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=02.03.16
192.168.1.1;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=01.06.15
192.168.1.2;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=02.03.16
192.168.1.1;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=12.07.15
192.168.1.2;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=03.01.16
192.168.1.1;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=02.11.15
```

I need to extract only uniq entries where only once every IP occured. So it should be

```
192.168.1.1;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=02.03.16
192.168.1.2;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=02.03.16
```

No matter what come after IP. Log file is long. 
I guess it should be combination of **uniq -u** command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your dates are in mm.dd.yy format

```
sort -k1,1 -k3.12,3.13nr -k3.6,3.7nr -k3.9,3.10nr -t';' file  |
 sort -k1,1 -u -t';'

192.168.1.1;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=02.03.16
192.168.1.2;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=03.01.16
```

Sort by the IP field followed by the date field in reverse order (thus the most recent dates for each IP sort first). Pipe this to another `sort`, this time by the IP field but specifying `-u` to ensure one record for each IP is returned. Since `-u` implies stable sort, the first record for each IP (the one with the most recent date) is returned

If your dates on the other hand are in dd.mm.yy format

```
sort -k1,1 -k3.12,3.13nr -k3.9,3.10nr -k3.6,3.7nr -t';' file |
sort -k1,1 -u -t';'

192.168.1.1;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=02.03.16
192.168.1.2;query=/etc/security/limits.conf;date=02.03.16
```

Comment: Could you please explain how -k works ? From man:  -k, --key=KEYDEF sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type    Actually this short works for my task sort -t\; -uk1,1 someone posted and deleted this. But you gave very advanced sorting, good job!

Comment: @Demontager, you're probably better off looking at the description of  `-k` on the [info](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html) page for `sort`. Don't forget to check the examples at the end as well. These do a better job at explaining than I ever could